# Bootstrap Col-push and -pull not reordering as desired

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a login page where, at xs, I want it to look like:

[image: Login page at xs size]

and at >= sm it looks like:

[image: Login page at sm size]

The code for this is:

```
<div id="loginPanel" class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Log in to myBethany</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="divCredentials" runat="server" class="row">
                <label class="control-label sr-only" for="<%= tbUsername.ClientID %>">
                    Username 
                </label>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-offset-1 form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                    <input type="text" id="tbUsername" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="username" />
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback always-show"></i>
                </div>
                <label class="control-label sr-only" for="<%= tbPassword.ClientID %>">
                    Password
                </label>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                    <input type="password" id="tbPassword" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="pass phrase" />
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback always-show"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 form-group">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary form-control" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" Text="login" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-11" id="joinLink" style="text-align: right; padding-top: 8px">
                    New to myBethany? 
                    <a href="#" onclick="showJoin();">Create an account</a>!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now I want to insert an error message:

```
<div id="divCredentialsMessage" runat="server" class="col-xs-12 well">
    <div class="">My error message</div>
</div>
```

At all sizes I want the error message immediately under the username/password.

So at xs it should look like:

[image: Login page with error message at xs size]

and at >= sm:

[image: Login page with error message at sm size]

Note that the error message and the login button positionally switched places.  From what I've read, this should mean that I insert my error message code between the password and the login button code.  Then I add the `col-sm-push-2` class to the error message div, and the `col-sm-pull-12` class to the login button div.

At xs, everything looks as desired--which makes sense; nothing's changed yet.

When I set the window to sm or wider, the result I'm getting is:

[image: login window at sm with push and pull added]

The button, rather than joining the inputs at the top, has moved all the way left off the screen, and the error message has moved from col-0 to col-2, but maintained its 12-col width.

I've tried resizing the error message to col-4, keeping its push at 2, and set the login button to pull-4.  Even though there are three available columns at the top, and the button is only 2 wide, it refuses to move up.

From what I gather from other stackoverflow posts, this is because I'm reversing the order of two divs on the boundary of the all-important column-12.

Is there a clean solution to this?

EDIT: Per comment, here's a repro on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4vgvkun/2/)

And here's a screenshot of where the login button is positioned when the JSFiddle output window is widened to small size.

[image]

Comment: Reproduce the problem on a fiddle.

Comment: push and pull work horizontally at the min width. You trying to move rows, essentially.

Comment: @Aaron I added a jsfiddle repro

Comment: @Christina I don't know the inner workings of Bootstrap, but my understanding is that you can put as many columns in a single row as you want and it just pushes content down if you try to use more than 12 columns.  Push and pull, then, just add and subtract from which column something is logically placed at.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Since you have your inputs, then your error well, then the button in that order, the button isn't going to magically snap back up to the form group after a certain point, especially since you have the error box as length of 12 which means anything after it will always appear on the next row. I honestly think you'd be better off displaying error messages above the username and passphrase inputs, and maybe disabling the login button as long as there are errors.

Comment: @dfoverdx - no that's not correct. It will push it down and if all are precisely the same height at all viewport widths they there won't be a float issue, but 99.9999% this is not the case and it won't clear. You are supposed to have 12 columns per row OR have a responsive utility clearfix per 12 col to prevent float issues. And you cannot move stuff top to bottom with push and pull, look at the css for these classes it's based on the relative position of the column left or negative left. col-sm-push-6 is left:50% and the pull is left:-50%

Comment: @dfoverdx It looks fine on my screen.